# IE9 not support globalCompositeOperation, Knights of the Round game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was submitting a smallgame to IE9 contest in China. But it seems IE9 beta not support canvas2d globalCompositeOperation property. No metter what I did, the result looks like 'copy', I cannot but use a special picture instead of it in IE9 beta.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Preview url:

http://ie9.onlinevoc.cn/contest/PercodPage.aspx?ID=43

It's supported by IE9 beta, Chrome7+, Safari5+ and Firefox 3.6+. If you feel the game is good, please vote for me, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I have created a library called [context-blender](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender) that allows you to perform Photoshop-style blend effects between regions of two canvases. It does not use `globalCompositeOperation`. You can view the [README](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender#readme) to see the modes supported so far. If you have another composite mode that you need supported, let me know and I'll add it.